# How would i strikethorugh list items which are completed in Todolist in React?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code in which i wanted to strike through the completed list item.

```
export default class Todo extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            text:"",
            todoList:[],
            strikeThrough:[]
        }
    }
```

I am just getting confuse how to use the css property of line through in react components and how would it take that particular index to be updated.

```
doneTodo=index => ()=>{
    const list3=[...this.state.todoList];
    this.setState({todoList:list3})
};

render() {
    let {text,todoList}=this.state;
    return(
            <div className="App-header">
                <div className="childApp">
                <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>To-Do APP!</h1>
            <h3>You have {todoList.length} Todos</h3>
            <br/>
            <ul className="list-group">
                {todoList.map((val,index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="mytodo">
                            <li className="list-group-item">
          <span classname="spname"> {val} </span>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.doneTodo} className="btn btn-default btn-s pull-right remove-item">Done</button>
              <button key={index} id={index} class="btn btn-default btn-s pull-right remove-item" onClick={this.delTodo(index)}>
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
         </li>
```

Comment: Please, include full component code and sample data. Also, describe what you tried so far. This let us help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this (not necessary the only way), and the way I'd recommend you since you seem like a react beginner is like this:

since you already seem to have a class `mytodo` for all your todos, add the following css selector to your stylesheet:

```
.mytodo .done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

now what you will need to do, is add the class `done` to all your todos that are done.

To do that, I would suggest you change your code structure a bit, mainly by adding a `isDone` property to your todo object instead of using two arrays.

Now you would need to conditionally render the css class like this:

```
<div className=`myTodo ${todo.isDone ? 'done' : ''}`>
...
</div>
```

The only thing left do do now is to toggle the `isDone` property of each todo object. For that you could write a function like this:

```
setDone = todoId => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todoList: prevState.todoList.map(el => (el.id === todoId ? {...el, isDone: true} : el))
    }));
}
```

Lastly call the function on click and pass the id. Maybe with something like this:

```
<button onClick={() => setDone(todo.id)}>set done</button>
```

Comment: what is el referring to in the setDone fucntion?

Comment: i really dont understand the setDone function can you please help me in understanding it and also it is giving an error that id not defined in the setDone fucntion

Comment: hi @Beren, sorry I was away for a few hours. i fixed the error with "Id" is not defined. The error was shown because I named the variable that is passed inside the function "todoId" and tried to access its value with "id" instead of "todoId". You can copy the setDone function and it should work now.

Comment: @Beren el is short for "element", it is the current element that is looped from todoList with javascript map. basically i wrote "for each el (todo) in todolist check if the id's match and if they do, set isDone to true). Feel free to rename it to anything you like, such as "todo" or "todoItem".